# How can I speed up a Spark job that transforms a large denormalized dataset into a parquet file with multiple struct schemas?

Tags: scala, performance, apache-spark, optimization

I'm trying to use Spark to transform a denormalized dataset into a structure that groups data into columns, where each column has its own `struct` schema.

I have an input parquet file with data that looks like this:

```
timestamp, device, measurement, value
1685305112, device1, ac_current, 100 
1685305112, device1, dc_current, 50
1685305112, device2, dc_voltage, 12
1685305113, device3, resistance, 1
```

The input data is on the order of 100s of GB, and has about 50 distinct devices.  Each device has about 50 distinct measurements.

I want it the output to look like this (I'm using the `{}` to represent a `struct`):

```
timestamp,  device1,                            device2,           device3
1685305112, { ac_current: 100, dc_current: 50 },{ dc_voltage: 12 }, null
1685305113, null,                               null,               { resistance: 1 }
```

And I need the job to complete in less than 6 hours.

The schema of the structs is an input to the Spark job, so I know what all the device names are and which measurements belong to which devices.

This is what I tried:

```
val df = spark.read.parquet(...)

// pivot the input DF on measurement
val pivotedDF = df
    .groupBy('timestamp)
    .pivot('measurement)
    .agg(first(value))

// I know device names and measurement names for each device ahead of time
// so I can loop over each device name and each measurement name and create a struct
val finalDF = deviceList.foldLeft(pivotedDF)((intermediateDF, device) => {
    val structifiedDF = intermediateDF.withColumn(device.name, 
        struct(
            device.measurementNames.foldLeft(Nil: List[Column])((columns, measurementName) => {
                col(measurementName)
            }): _*
        )
    )

    // drop used measurement columns
    structifiedDF.transform(df => {
        device.measurementNames.foldLeft(structifiedDF)((intermediateDF, measurementName) => {
            intermediateDF.drop(measurementName)
        })
    })
})
```

This code produces the output I want, but only works for small datasets (10 MB) with small device lists (5).  A long list of devices (50) makes the driver take hours just to build the DataFrame, and a large input dataset (I tested with 140GB input) runs for 10s of hours.

Is there a more efficient way to accomplish what I need here?